# How to use 2 D-link wireless N 300 Routers in the same Network

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking

We have a to apartment house with the main internet in apartment A" with the main D-link router and i am in apartment "B" about 100m from the main apartment.
I have use a long network cable to bring internet signal to my desktop in my room.Now I have a second Dlink router that i want to add in my room so as to have WiFi in my room to be able to use internet in my phone and my ipad,i need it desperately on these two devices.
Now my problem is i do not know how to configure this second Dlink N 300 wireless router in my room to work on the same network since there is already a dlink router from where i get my signal via a LAN cable,can any body help me configure this router so i have wifi working?
Thanks so much for your quick reply.

Answer (score -1):

u have to configure the second router to different subnet ex 192.168.2.1

Comment: Just configuring a different subnet won't do. There's a whole lot more to configure to the WAN interface of the second router.

Comment: I tried configuring the second router with a different subnet and disabling the DHCP option from the second router so that only first router assigns IP address to devices connected to the router but then no device is able to obtain an IP address now,everything is just stock now

Comment: I had the same problem before I connected the main router sagemcom (192.168.1.1) with ethernet cable to linksys internet port and changed the ip to (192.168.2.1) it worked for me dont disable the dhcp in the second router to get an ip 192.168.2.x if u want to disable it u configure ur pc with static ip ex 192.168.2.5